# cakephp предупреждение о ошибке авторизации

Tags: php, phpstorm, ide, auth, cakephp

Решил пройти туториал по последней версии cakephp (3.5.14). Но при попытке сделать метод проверки авторизации, IDE предуприждает о ошибке

Return type declaration must be compatible with Controller->isAuthorized(user):bool

[image: ошибка которую выдает IDE]

Comment: ну дак  где у вас `:bool` то?

Comment: `return false;`

Comment: это не декларация типа возвращаемого значения, это его возврат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В заголовке вашего вопроса из 4х слов верными в принципе являются только одно - *предупреждение*. В целом ошибки тут нет, как к таковой авторизации это все не относится, да и cakephp особо ни при чем.

Читайте что говорит вам среда разработки:

> Return type declaration must be compatible with `Controller->isAuthorized(user):bool`

Надо всего лишь прочитать, перевести и понять, о чем речь. А говорится, что

> декларация возвращаемого типа должна быть совместима с `Controller->isAuthrorized($user):bool`.

Ключевое тут, *декларация возвращаемого типа*. И вам приведен пример `... :bool`, а где у вас декларация типа результата? Ее нет, отсюда и ошибка, или как сказано в самом начале - предупреждение. Причем предупреждение среды, пхп вам вообще ничего не скажет об этом, т.к. с точки зрения языка тут ошибок нет.

> **[Объявление типов возвращаемых значений](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.returning-values.php)**
>   В PHP 7 добавлена возможность объявлять тип возвращаемого значения. Аналогично объявлению типов аргументов можно задать тип значения, которое будет возвращаться функцией. Типы, которые можно объявить для возвращаемых значений те же, что и для аргументов функций.

В целом класс `Controller` вообще не имеет метода `isAuthorized`. Он делегируется `AuthComponent` (magic-метод так сказать). PhpStorm тут ссылается на аннотацию к классу `Controller`:

```
* @method bool isAuthorized($user)
```

а в [самом классе `Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent` объявление метода](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/source-class-Cake.Controller.Component.AuthComponent.html#) имеет следующий вид

```
public function isAuthorized($user = null, ServerRequest $request = null)
```

В общем можете игнорировать данное оповещение среды. Особенно в условиях, что это magic-метод.

Comment: если я правильно вас понял `public function isAuthorized($user = null) :bool
    {
        return false;
    }`

Comment: @SanyaLavrechko `(bool) false`  то зачем? а в объявление можно попробовать вписать `:bool`, да. Если это не приведет к ошибкам со стороны пхп :) иначе просто забить на это оповещение, IDE тоже могут перемудрить. Формально тут наследования и перекрытия нет, поэтому объявляйте как хочется.

Comment: Спасибо) Оно действительно ошибок никаких не выдает, но все же глаза режит